# Removing MJAudioRecorder from sound preferences in macOS Mojave?

Tags: system-sounds

I'm trying to remove MJAudioRecorder from my machine. Is this file associated with anything else? I don't remember ever installing it. Thanks to this site, I successfully removed Boom2.

See screenshot:

[image: My machine's sound preferences]

Answer (score 3):

- Open `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL` folder in finder.
- Delete the `MJRecorderDevice.driver` folder.
- Restart

edit:
Also check `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`. I had a file `com.mingjie.mjrecorder.agent.plist` there.